# How to change columns number when resizing browser window?

Tags: angular, angular-gridster2

I am creating board with rectangular cards and I'm using angular-gridster2 library.
I`m using VerticalFixed grid type and defaoult it have three colums. Is it posible to set a breakpoint and set two columns for some browser width?

Answer (score 0):

you can use mobileBreakpoint?: number;
eg.:

```
options: GridsterConfig;
options.mobileBreakpoint= 500;
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late, but I made a systeme to recalculate columns based on available size. it works well until you reach the first widget. when i try to set a col count smaller thant what is used already, the systeme is dropping my value and juste resizes. Still it works prety well.

logic is : take the width of screen, divide it by the size of the col you want, take a ceil or floor to have an int, set that int to the grid and tel it to refresh.
/* rowHeight is a constant set to 140 (px) in my case */

```
calculateLayout() {
var contentWindow:HTMLElement = document.querySelector(".app-mainContent"); //container of the grid
this.cols = Math.ceil(contentWindow.offsetWidth/this.rowHeight);
this.rows = Math.ceil(contentWindow.offsetHeight/this.rowHeight);
if (!this.options) {
  this.options = {
    itemChangeCallback: this.itemChange,
    itemResizeCallback: this.itemResize,
    outerMargin: false,
    minCols: this.cols,
    maxCols: this.cols,
    minRows: this.rows,
    maxRows: this.rows,
    draggable: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    resizable: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    pushItems: true,
  };
} else {
  this.options.minCols = this.cols;
  this.options.maxCols = this.cols;
  this.options.minRows = this.rows;
  this.options.maxRows = this.rows;
}
console.log("calculated columns based on width", this.cols);
console.log("calculated rows based on height", this.rows);
this.options.api.optionsChanged();
```

}

than I call this function on load and on window resize event.

Answer (score 0):

just insert a property in gridster options to achieve this
"( disableWindowResize: true )"

```
gridsterOptions =  {
  gridType: GridType.ScrollVertical,
  displayGrid: DisplayGrid.OnDragAndResize,
  pushItems: true,
  pushDirections: { north: false, east: false, south: true, west: false },
  
  swap: false,
  minCols: 12,
  maxCols: 24,
  minRows: 12,
  maxRows: 60,

  draggable: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  resizable: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  disableWindowResize: true,
};
```

Answer (score -1):

set resizable.enabled = true when initialize grid item

for more refer https://tiberiuzuld.github.io/angular-gridster2/resize

Comment: I've already done that but the point is to stop resizing and reduce the number of columns during resizing window.

Comment: please try to define column numbers by divide screen width

Answer (score -1):

I mean

0 - 600px - mobile;
601px - 900px - two  columns;
900px - up - three columns;

How to do that with verticalFixed grid type?

Comment: @Barosz Stepak Do you got the solution for this? I want to implement the same functionality.Thanks.